Flowbite-vue dropdown transitions not working
I have an issue with the FwbDropdown component.
I'm trying to use the transition prop for this component, to add a transition when it opens but it is not recognized.
Example:
<fwb-dropdown transition="fade">

I tried several fade,  expand transition modes but nothing worked. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way.

The flowbite-vue documentation gives no information as to how this prop actually works.  The source code however makes it clear that the prop functions as the name prop of Vue's <Transition> component. This implies that you must also provide the relevant transition classes as described in the Vue documentation. As a benefit, you can create the exact transition effect you want.
<style>
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>

